# How to purge a package AND its installed dependencies?

Tags: debian, package-management, aptitude

I only want to delete the dependencies if they are not required by any package installed since then.

For example, when I installed subversion, it also installed some libs:

libapr1:amd64
libaprutil1:amd64
libneon27-gnutls:amd64
libsvn1:amd64

I want to purge them also along with subversion if this will not break my system.

I'm looking for an implicit way, eg. aptitude purge subversion and some switches to tell aptitude what I want.

My favourite package manager is pure aptitude.

How to do that on Debian Wheezy?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `deborphan` package to look for libraries no longer fulfilling any dependencies. It will generate a simple list of all these packages.

One can also use this list directly with `aptitude` by

```
sudo aptitude purge $(deborphan)
```

which will send all these supposed unused packages as arguments to `aptitude`, as one would expect. `aptitude` will then show you the exact actions that will be taken and their consequences, and if you approve, these packages will be cleared.

`deborphan` can also be given a package name as argument to act on a single package's dependencies instead of system-wide. As always, see the man page.

Comment: I still not understand something or it is not working. Tried with python3, which installed the related python3 minimal packages too (python3-minimal:amd64, python3.2:amd64, python3.2-minimal:amd64). Right after that I removed python3 and run you command. I doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

you will get some hints anyway after removing 'subversion'. Mostly 'apt-get autoremove --purge' will purge every excess package. I don't use 'aptitude' - possibly there is some equivalent to autoremove.

Answer (score 0):

You can also mark packages as being installed automatically which will cause aptitude to suggest removing them when nothing depends on them. You marks the package by pressing `M`.